# How do you implement a closure that's an argument in a Swift 3 method?

Tags: swift

An example method signature from WKWebView:

```
func evaluateJavaScript(_ javaScriptString: String, 
      completionHandler: ((Any?, Error?) -> Void)? = nil)
```

How does one correctly implement this method to be able to capture the `Any?` and `Error?` arguments in the completionHandler closure? I want to be able to use both of them in a `print` statement for instance. I can't seem to get the syntax correct for the implementation, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
evaluateJavaScript(javaScriptString: yourString, completionHandler: { result, error in 
   if let error = error {
      print("error: \(error)")
   }

   if let result = result {
      print("result: \(result)")
   }

   // Your code here
})
```